# minimal example requirement

Tags: discussion

The comments in this put-on-hold question [R data.table by= fails to group by](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38384895/1568919) asked for a minimal example. I have indicated that I tried and wasn't able to, and one of the voter also tried and failed. I showed how I produced the error, the obvious wrong result, and a way that fixes the problem -- I don't understand why the fix works, hence the question.

One comment actually answered the question (it's a bug) and the minimal example he/she gave [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1704) is far from simple. I think it's too demanding in this case.

Comment: The minimal example doesn't look that bad to me - although it also looks like it can be simplified further. But try to look at it from the perspective of someone wanting to answer your question - you've basically said "Something's wrong, but all I can show you is it working properly." Unless you already know about the bug, how can anyone help with that?

Comment: "The minimal example doesn't look that bad to me" -- that's this question is about. For me it is too advanced and I have to learn a lot before I can make that example. That guy is a developer for the package, and it's not easy for him to identify the bug. The "you must provide a minimal example" rule should have a limit -- eg "an ordinary user without a  software engineer background has shown an effort to do it"

Comment: But do you understand that it's only partly about showing that you've made an effort - it's mostly making the question answerable. If you've got an odd result that you can't reproduce in a form that you can show people, you're basically asking people to be psychic in order to work out what's wrong. That kind of thing just doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: Then the experts here can comment and point towards a possible direction. A non reproducible error gives most frustration and that's when I need help most. Why is it not ok to ask for expert advice but not expert solution?

Comment: Have a deep look on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for tips on how to create a mcve for R. I don't buy you wasn't able to subset your data into 20 lines reproducing the problem and calling `dput` on those indices.

Comment: @Tensibai trust me I tried. But I have to hide some private data. And the moment I touched the raw data, the error goes away (as you see in my trivial fix in the question).

Comment: Your fix overwrite a column, subsetting should not change the keying, i.e: `samp <- xx[1:20,.SD,.SDcols=c('mkt','t2')]` should give you a reproducible example. A least a `str(xx)` with private datas overwritten would giv an idea about the keys of your data.table. (All of this so next time you can have tips to give insight on your structure)

Comment: It doesn't scale for SO users to spend their time making random suggestions. Unreproducible errors suck, I know, but that's something you'll just have to live with; we cannot help without a clearly defined problem, and it's not something that's useful to future users.

Comment: Part of the issue is it seems you want Stack Overflow to be a help desk or maybe a forum where people will drop in and provide little tidbits to help you piece together your issue.  However, SO was designed to be close to a community moderated wiki/Q&A site where questions and answers are supposed to have last value and help other people.  Questions are expected to be searchable to help other people with the same problem find the question.  But if you can reproduce your problem, the question is really not going to provide any kind of value to anyone by you.

Comment: so, 100% that MCVE isn`t necessarily easy. But YOU benefit more than ANYONE from doing it. Half of the time building your MCVE will find you issue. Anyway, that doesn't change the fact that coming here with "I can't reproduce, but there's a bug" is tantamount to "My car doesn't start. WHAT DO?" You CAN get help, but it doesn't mean your question is answerable...

Answer (score 7):

The point of a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example is that you provide a completly clear description of how to produce the erroneous output, a completly clear description of the desired correct output, and any error(s) you get in the process. Then, secondary to that, you should try and reproduce your given problem with as little code and logic as possible (narrowing it down).

You state that:

> I'm not able to make a reproducible short example and the way to make
>   xx is quite complicated involving data table joins and private data.

But how is anyone supposed to help you if all you can say about it is that "Its wrong" but not what you wanted to begin with and the current wrong output. How are we supposed to verify that the problem is not buried in the part of the code you didn't show us? Why should answerers poke into the dark when the real problem might not even be visible to them? Remember, you asked the question, so you don't know what is causing this. Thats why you create a minimal example: To make sure that whatever is causing this can be found and solved within the information you posted.

The primary purpose of this site is not to solve everybody's debugging problems no matter what it takes, it is to create high quality and useful Q/A for everyone. A question where experts blindly troubleshoot your problem until they, by mere chance, hit the issue is, while very useful to you, entirely useless for future visitors.

As it currently is, I wouldn't vote to reopen this question.